# Is SO3(C) an amenable group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, amenability

It is well known that SO(3) is an example of non-amenable group, but it is not so easy to find information about the amenability of its complex counterpart.

Comment: The free group $F_2$ is not amenable. It is also a subgroup of $SO_3(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Since you know that $SO(3)$ is non-amenable, you know that its overgroup $SO(3)(C)$ is also non-amenable (since amenability passes to subgroups).